# Massive filesystem corruption after latest update on LUKS encrypted drive

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, encryption, fsck

I booted my machine this morning and was greeted by a `busybox` shell.
I booted from a live USB, mounted the drive with `cryptsetup`, but when I try to open it it says my `ubunutu--root-vg` has an *unrecognized filesystem*.

So I ran `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--root-vg` and it says *possible bad superblocks*, scans the drive for a minute, and then starts endlessly spitting out block numbers that look like `(9232934579-9232934589)`. I think it's trying to tell me that all of these blocks are bad or something. But the command is still running spitting out random block names.

Does this mean all of my data is gone forever? All I did was apply the latest Ubuntu update. How could that corrupt my entire drive?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  ;-) **So please, [edit] your question, remove the "solved" from the title, and copy your "answer" from your question to the answer section below.**  After a few days you can "accept" your answer as "valid" by clicking the grey check-mark...

Answer (score 1):

Answer from OP:

Solved by letting `fsck` run for about an hour of random output. I thought it might be glitched out but it was doing its job properly. Imagine my excitement when it completed and all my files were back :)